# Apple's push notification server version 2 dropping a message that seems valid

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Apple's push notification server version 2 drops this message:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 1,
        "alert": {
            "loc-key": "New message from %@",
            "loc-args": ["joe"]
        },
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "arg": "value"
}
```

But it delivers this message:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 1,
        "alert": {
            "loc-key": "New message from",
            "loc-args": ["joe"]
        },
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "arg": "value"
}
```

Not only is the message not delivered but no http2 response is received and the connection is not disconnected.

I'm testing with apple's development service.

The app doesn't have a Localizable.strings file for the language (english).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that as soon as a 'loc-key' contains a '%@' it can't be localized.

Moving the %@ from the key into a value in Localization.strings works.